# How can I add background color with a non-rectangular shape to my prompt string(PS1)?

Tags: bash, prompt

I want to make prompt string(PS1) like this one.

How can I do?

[image]

Comment: That *looks* like oh-my-zsh, which is (as you might guess) only for zsh, not bash.  (Not saying there isn't something like that for Bash, but I haven't seen it.)

Comment: @Wildcard Displaying this is just a matter of sending the right characters to the terminal. Bash can do it just as well as zsh. Or dash for that matter.

Comment: @Wildcard That’s exactly what I want to know. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Now it's exactly what is shown in snapshot:

Add this into your ~/.bashrc

```
PS1="\[\e[34;45m\]\w\[\e[m\]\[\e[35m\]▶\[\e[m\] "
```

It depend on the font and angle character you can find better fit one.

You may have a look here for [Power-line style prompt](https://github.com/banga/powerline-shell) also.

Comment: The arrow symbol used in the prompt above will not use the whole available line height. If you install one or several font(s) from https://github.com/powerline/fonts, you can use the character with code uE0B0 (this is a "private use area" character, so it is shown as  in most non-Powerline-patched fonts) to get a nicer arrow.